# Ember js: How to increment a property in a controller while it is consumed in the template?

Tags: ember.js, properties

How to increment a property in a controller  while it is consumed in the template?

**Case : I will consume same component multiple times in a template and I want to calculate how many times I've used that component in my template and I also want which component(tracking each component) gets destroyed When I do some actions.
So what I thought was a give a specific number to each component and Track it down using its hooks by using a property which would increment each time I access the component**

Note: If there is any other way to track each component among others, kindly post them too and Thanks...

Comment: is it not possible to know ahead of time since you're passing the property? Do you need to know from many different components or just a single type of component?You could always invoke a passed action in `didInsertElement` that's handled by a controller. You could also wrap the "property" in a helper that increments a value on a service. It's not clear from your three line question what you *really* need

Comment: Thanks for the time .I've updated my question kindly see it.

Answer (score 4):

Your case to find the number of times a component is used can be implemented using a service along with a component hook.

You'll need to create a [service](https://guides.emberjs.com/release/tutorial/service/) to maintain the count with an increment function and call the increment function from the [init](https://www.emberjs.com/api/ember/3.6/classes/Component/methods/init?anchor=init) hook of the component.

So, the increment function will be called everytime a new instance of the component is created.

You can find a working example [here](https://ember-twiddle.com/d1ba8b3ef5e795ff183da57a4ff0f73f?openFiles=services.counter-service.js%2Ctemplates.components.counted-component.hbs)

Comment: Don't forget to decrement the property when a component gets destroyed